# bind Data table to chart in vb

Tags: vb.net, charts, bind

I have a project that im working on at the moment in VB.
Basically I have a Data Table in VB it populates with 4 columns and a variable number of rows, the column names are as follows;

```
Gear, RPM, Speed, CO2
```

The data table appears in datagridview correctly but that's as far as I have gotten :/

What I am trying to do is to make a line chart called mainGraph to draw a graph based on these results, I'm getting stuck when trying to populate the chart.

ANY thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: please show the code that you've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using the ms chart controls and not some 3rd party like Telerik.

This should be usefull http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx

Also, there is source code found at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418

Answer (score 0):

in short this is a way to get things displayed

```
mainGraph.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
mainGraph.Series(0).Points.DataBind(yourDataTable.DefaultView, "Speed", yourDataTable.DefaultView, "Gear")
```

These commands should make a line graph with Speed on your x axis, and Gear on your Y.  Assigned to "Series(0)"
To add more columns, you need to add more "Series"

```
mainGraph.Series.Add("RPM")
```

Do some thinking about how you want this data displayed.
how would you like to set this graph up?
I'm assuming you would want a line graph?
What is going to be the X axis?  Is there a missing column that needs to be "time" in the data table?
do you want them all on one graph/chart area?
If you would like more charts, then you need to add chart areas.  A series can be assigned to a chart area.

Hopefully this helps.